# How to dynamically size a view depending on the label within it?

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uilabel, constraints

**Problem**

I have a UIViewController containing a TableView. Each cell (2) of the TableView contains a UIView and a Label within said view. I am currently having trouble resizing the view when the label exceeds a single line. Below I have attached my current settings within the storyboard. None of my view code is currently relevant to the resizing; I am trying to do this through storyboard but I'm open to a programatic solution.

I've tried changing the lines to 0, changing the hugging priority, changing the line breaks to word wrap, and constraining the edges of the label to the view, all to no avail.

Is there a way to get the boxes to follow the size of the label?

**Messages**

[image: Description]

**Storyboard Cells**

[image: Description]

**Label Attributes**

[image: Description]

**Label Size 1**

[image: Description]

**Label Size 2**

[image: Description]

**View Size 1**

[image: Description]

**View Size 2**

[image: Description]

Comment: The thing is, I'm not trying to resize the cell; I'm trying to resize a view within the cell.

Comment: what you mean resizing view. you mean tableViewCell resizing to fit its content?

Comment: No, there is actually an added blank View within my tableViewCell (as shown in the second image). The label is inside of that nested View.

Comment: so you have 2 prototype label inside your tableViewCell.is anything special about your UIView or you just placing an another label using UIView..can you describe what those two label for.

Comment: The labels have to do with a chat room. The 1st label is for the sender Cell and the 2nd label is for the receiver Cell. The labels are for messages, the UIView is the outline of said messages without taking up the entirety of the cell.